# Angular select with ng-repeat doesnt work on json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The Above code works but it leaves me unable to retrieve the id field of the option element. See the different Plunker - working example with `value={{option.id}}` https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview - example with `value={{option}}` https://plnkr.co/edit/iEoHaSYLZbnwId8zHi9U?p=preview.

If I use ng-options in select it works - https://plnkr.co/edit/iEoHaSYLZbnwId8zHi9U?p=preview.

Do I need to filter ng-model?

Comment: what do you want? if your `availableOptions` have id enitity in it then id will be fetched by you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve the id because by passing the option object in `value` you're converting it to a string, so `data.model` became `"{"id":"1","name":"Option A"}"`. In order to pass the object use instead ng-value:

```
  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
    <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question the below code should work

```
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <!--<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model" ng-options="option as option.name for option in data.availableOptions">-->
    <!--    </select>-->
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
```